# disable background color where press any tag

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have some problem.
I write application for  android with webview. Screenshot http://oi61.tinypic.com/21n48yd.jpg.

Where I press on like the background is painted in blue color.

```
<div id="other_user_action" class="_other_user_action">
                            <a href="#" onclick="updateLike(15); return false;" id="15" class="15"> Like 1 </a><a href="#comm_15">  Comment  </a>
 </div>
```

How I can use css disable this background painted? 
thank you.

Comment: It will be easier if you post your css code.

Comment: ._other_user_action
    {
        margin-left: auto; 
        width: 150px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in the css

`-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Refer this link: http://danbarnett.net/how-to-hide-android-webview-highlight-border-or-change-its-color-142.html